# I can't find ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

I want to use ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), and I have downloaded Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.11.3, and i have clicked the ASP.NET and web devleopment before i download it

but I can't find the one i needed, I don't want the 'core' one,

does anyone know how to solve it?

[I have click and downloaded the ASP.NET and web development at workload at installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iopl.png)

[Can't find the ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framwork) for C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYq0b.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be included. There is a TRUCK load of additonal options.

Perhaps you check some of these:

[image]

So, from VS go tools->Get Tools and features, and check the above.

See the "additional" project templates in above - try checking that.

Edit:---------------------
So, I now have these templates:
[image]

Comment: Ya, I have follow ur method to do checking, and added the addtional project templates, but only the .NET Core 2.1 Runtime is out of support,  other all i have aldy clicked but still cant't solve it

Comment: Couldn't install Microsoft.Ancm.IISExpress.Msi,  will this affected?

Comment: I would launch vs as a admin. Same goes for install, or  repair. But, yes, you will need IIS express. See me edit to my answer: the first 3 templates are the ones you would use for creating asp.net web site, or a asp.net web application (preferred). You could as noted do a repair from teh installed programs - but either you missed some of the templates during installing. As noted, I would ALWAYS run the install as an admin.

Comment: And I assume you selected most of the previous .net frameworks during this process?

Comment: Thank you so much, after I try the repair then finally can found what I needed, really thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Install the `.NET Framework project and item templates` component, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Create new project with .Net Framework]

Filter by C#, Windows and Web and if you scroll down you will find it.

Comment: This I try aldy, also only filter out those with 'core' one, even i download the 2022 preview one, also can't find out

Comment: Do you have the individual components for .Net SDK and .NET Framework development tools?